# Display foreign key description instead of value with AJAX / Multiple sql statements in output

Tags: javascript, php, sql, ajax, mysqli

In general I work with 3 different tables (3 Levels) and they each have a reference to the previous table with a foreign key. Second Level table has a foreign key which references the previous and also the third level table which references the 2nd table.
I'm currently displaying all these values in multiselect dropdowns. The third level multiselect dropdown is currently displaying the foreign key value from the 2nd level multiselect dropdown. All I want to do is change the foreign key value to display the description which is inside the 2nd level table. 
This is how it currently looks with the foreign key values in optgroup:
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/LqKHi.jpg)

Up to now I always did this by creating another sql statement which selects the the description based on the id from the 2nd level table. I'm not sure how I can do this since currently I have a javascript with a multiselect function which is accessing a php file over ajax which includes the sql statement with the output.
To provide a better overview I attached the important code parts:

```
//Javascript
$('#idsecondlevel').multiselect({
        onChange:function(option, checked){
            //Store selected value in array format in selected variable
            var selected = this.$select.val();
            if(selected.length > 0){
                $.ajax({
                    url:"http://localhost:8080/fetch_xx.php",
                    method:"POST",
                    data:{selected:selected},
                    success:function(data){
                        $('#idthirdlevel').html(data);
                        $('#idthirdlevel').multiselect('rebuild');
                    }
                })
            }
        }  
    });
```

```
//fetch_xx.php
include 'dbconnect.php';
if(isset($_POST["selected"])){
    $id = join("','", $_POST["selected"]);
    $sql= "SELECT * FROM 3rdlevel WHERE foreign_key_2ndlevel IN ('".$id."')";
    $res=mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
    $output = '';
    foreach($res as $row){
        $output .= '<optgroup label="'.$row["foreign_key_2ndlevel"].'"><option value="'.$row["primary_key_3rdlevel"].'">'.$row["desc_3dlevel"].'</option></optgroup>';
    }
    echo $output;
}
```

Do I need to make another sql statement before the isset function and add it to the output where I currently have $row["foreign_key_2ndlevel"]? Or do I need to make another sql statement in the output which chooses the description of the 2ndlevel based on the id, which would make it very messy? I currently have no idea where to add this statement.
A possible sql statemtent would be:

```
$sql= SELECT desc_2ndlevel FROM 2ndlevel WHERE primary_key_2ndlevel = foreign_key_2ndlevel;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just to make sure I'm getting this right: The contents of 2nd and 3rd level are appearing dynamically, based on the selected value(s) from its parent table. So basically, you want the user to select something/multiple things on 2nd-level table, and then make him go into more detail on the 3rd level? 
In your screenshot you marked the 1, 2 etc. You want to display the description of the selected id from the parent table there?

If so, to avoid another SELECT-statement you could use JOINS. Looking at your code, you might want to use INNER JOIN. To give you an example of a third-level SELECT, check pseudo-code below. You might want to display the classification history in a URL-like way (like 'abc/xyz' as title with 3rd-level options below), therefore you'd need the first level description as well. In case you don't, just remove the respective columns. To integrate with your php, just compare against the id of your selected option.

```
SELECT a.id, a.description, b.id, b.foreign_key_firstlevel, b.description, c.id, c.foreign_key_secondlevel, c.description
    FROM first_level_table AS a
    INNER JOIN second_level_table AS b ON a.id = b.first_level_foreignkey
    INNER JOIN third_level_table AS c ON b.id = c.second_level_foreignkey;
```

Another thing that comes to mind: The contents of level 1 - 3 are pretty static right, so why not use a View? Of course this comes with limitations, but since you only seem to select values this shouldn't bother you. Joins require a lot of computation and slow down your calculation if done excessively. You could get around that using a prepared View. Since I don't know your database structure, pseudocode could look something like this:

```
CREATE VIEW view_allselectoptions AS 
    SELECT a.id, a.description, b.id, b.foreign_key_firstlevel, b.description, c.id, c.foreign_key_secondlevel, c.description
        FROM first_level_table AS a, second_level_table AS b, third_level_table AS c
        WHERE a.id = b.foreign_key_firstlevel
            AND b.id = c.foreign_key_secondlevel;
```

You could use JOINS in the view as well. Code would be similiar to the one above.

Comment: Thanks a lot Lino! I created a view in the way as you described above and had to add INNER JOIN as well for it to work properly. So the finalized version with 2 Levels would be:

CREATE VIEW view_allselectoptions AS 
    SELECT a.id, a.description, b.id, b.foreign_key_firstlevel, b.description
        FROM first_level_table 
       INNER JOIN first_level_table
         AS a, second_level_table AS b
         ON a.id = b.foreign_key_firstlevel;